# requirements of Google+ sign-in for android

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate google+ sign-in in my android app. I want to ask that does it required to have google+ app installed on the host phone for someone to sign in my app through their google+ account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO.
Google+ app isn't needed at all. Only the latest google play services library is needed for the app to run on a device. And mostly this library is available on most phones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as per the latest docs:

reference:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started